# Setting system volume in a bash script (in linux)

Tags: linux, bash, audio, alsa

I need to set the system volume in a bash script, but I have no idea how to do this.
Should I use `alsactl`? Are there some values in `/proc` or `/sys` that I could use?

Comment: Found what I was looking for; amixer. For instance 'amixer set Master 75%' will set the master volume to 75% :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [amixer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer) tool.

Run `amixer` without parameters to get a list of mixer controls.
Use commands like this:

```
amixer set Master 50%     # set absolute
amixer set Master 2dB+    # set relative
amixer set Master unmute
```

Comment: `amixer set Master 2dB+` not working for me, `amixer -D pulse sset Master 2%+` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `pactl`.

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 60%  # set absolute
pactl set-sink-volume 0 +10% # set relative
pactl set-sink-mute 0 0      # unmute
```

In particular, the `pactl set-sink-mute 0 0` unmute command works on my computer where `amixer set Master unmute` doesn't.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, try statements like `pactl set-sink-volume 1 60%` (which means your device is no. 1 instead of no. 0)  I've never had my devices go past 1, however.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a nice vol script in my ~/bin to help me do the trick ...

```sh
#!/bin/sh

export XDIALOG_NO_GMSGS=1

case ${1} in
    +|-) VOL=( $(amixer set Master 10dB${1} |tail -1|tr -d "[]") )
        Xdialog --no-buttons --title "Vol" --infobox ${VOL[3]} 50x30+32+32 ;;
    *[0-9]) VOL=( $(amixer set Master "${1}%" |tail -1|tr -d "[]") )
        Xdialog --no-buttons --title "Vol" --infobox ${VOL[3]} 50x30+32+32 ;;
    *) printf "Usage: vol [+]|[-]|[0-100]\n" >&2 ;;
esac
```

If you don't have Xdialog installed a simple echo ${VOL[3]} will give you some alsamixer feedback.